# how to create gnome 3 extensions

Tags: gnome, gtk3, gnome-shell-extension

I have installed and enjoyed the extensions provided by gnome3. But I'm looking for tutorials and sites that explain how to create them.

Do I need to know GTK3 and CSS and Javascript?

I haven’t done any development activities on ubuntu/gnome so I'm pretty new at this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and visit the  [Gnome Developer Website](http://developer.gnome.org/)  there you can find all the documentation you'll need